# Method for Matlab and Java integration

Tags: java, matlab

How to create JAVA classes in MATLAB ?
I am totally new to MATLAB , so want some example code for demo, to integrate Matlab calculations in JAVA

Comment: While it is possible it usually is a bad idea. The required MCR will blow up the application and also require a serious amount of RAM (and may even be not available for your platform). Most people I know choose to implement the algorithm using free toolboxes.

Answer (score 1):

u can go with
http://www.mathworks.in/products/javabuilder/description2.html

it may helpful to you.